# Master Detail Report With EF In Stimulsoft Report

Tags: report, entity-framework-5, master-detail, stimulsoft

In my recently project I try using EF (DataBase First) as an ORM database mapper. And also I use stimulsoft report for showing data.
I wanna show data in stimul report using Business Objects and load filtered data from EF Context in it! I have related Entity with One-To-Many relations and I want show data in report after doing some filters.
for example:

```
var detailData=(from c in Context.BooksRevisions
               where c.RevisionNumber==3
               select c).ToList();

var masterData=(from d in detailData
                select d.Books).Distinct().ToList();
```

so here I have filtered master and detail data. I want send them to stimulsoft report with a Master-Detail structure but I can't determine which object is detail in report(It must create a hierarchical tree for master-detail but it doesn't create related objects. It just create 2 separated object as "Books" and "BooksRevisions" and I can't relate them together nowise).
I google that and I found a video for "Master-Detail Using Business Objects" but It doesn't show how master-detail objects are made and also it's not related to EF.

I try to send EF *IEnumerable<Books>* and *IEnumerable<BooksRevisons>* dynamically to design report in dynamic state. here was a big 
problem : Report always show all existing data in *detailData* (its because Navigation Property always point to all detail data)!

So how can I create a master-detail report using Entity Framework database first for filtered data?

Thanks in Advance,
Mohsen.

Comment: Did you define a relation between `Book` and `BookRevision` in the report?

Comment: Yes, But it shows EF default navigation properties as _Child Business Object_ and shows all data (Not my filtered data). I try to filter master and detail in separate LINQ queries and make separate List<Book> and List<BookRevision> objects to send the report. But I can't define a relation between Book and BookRevision in report and Stimul report just show default EF navigation property as _Child Business Objects_ .